# Flutter : Splash Screen with a duration and progress bar

Tags: android, flutter

I ama noob in to flutter and is now experimenting with flutter. I was trying to implement a splashscreen.
My requirements:

- The flash screen should appear 3 seconds at the time of app launch.
- It should disappear after 3 seconds.
- It should show a progress bar at    the time of displaying and
  complete within 3 seconds.

Comment: So what's the problem? This question is too vague.

Comment: Need a splash screen implementation code with a delay and progressbar @MikeSpeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

You can Use [**`Future.delayed()`**](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/flutter/0.0.33-dev/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html)

Constructor

```
Future.delayed(Duration duration, [ dynamic computation() ])
```

> Creates a future that runs its computation after a delay.
>
> The computation will be executed after the given duration has passed, and the future is completed with the result of the computation,
>
> If the duration is 0 or less, it completes no sooner than in the next event-loop iteration, after all microtasks have run.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  //  You action here
});
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: SplashScreen(),

  ));

//  runApp(HomePage());
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 2);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Registration');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlutterLogo(
          size: 100.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What about launch_background.xml . What all changes to be made there?

Answer (score 4):

```
return new SplashScreen(
    seconds: 4,
    navigateAfterSeconds: new HomeScreen(),
    title: new Text(
      'WELCOME TO KIDS MANIA',
      style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontFamily: 'Chunkfive'),
    ),
    image: Image.asset("images/splashlogo.png"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
    styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Chunkfive'),
    photoSize: 100.0,
    loaderColor: Colors.black,
);
```

Comment: Can you give some context around the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check the complete code here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SplashScreen(
        seconds: 14,
        navigateAfterSeconds: new AfterSplash(),
        image: new Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        photoSize: 100.0,
        );
  }
}

class AfterSplash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Welcome In SplashScreen Package"),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Done!",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add the dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  splashscreen:
```